# How does .net create an SHA1 hash?

Tags: .net, sha1

Are there built in techniques for doing this? What arguments does it expect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha1.aspx)

```
byte[] data = new byte[DATA_SIZE];
byte[] result; 

SHA1 sha = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider(); 
// This is one implementation of the abstract class SHA1.
result = sha.ComputeHash(data);
```